# Выполнять скрипт при видимом элементе jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Собственно мне нужно выполнять заливку текста другим цветом один раз как только я увижу его. Как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

```js
if ($('.text').is(':visible')) {
  $(this).addClass('color');
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
}

.color {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ea tenetur, quibusdam, dolor vel molestiae quos veritatis similique tempora dolorem tempore suscipit rerum obcaecati fugiat in, perspiciatis voluptatibus autem. Ipsam.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ea tenetur, quibusdam, dolor vel molestiae quos veritatis similique tempora dolorem tempore suscipit rerum obcaecati fugiat in, perspiciatis voluptatibus autem. Ipsam.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ea tenetur, quibusdam, dolor vel molestiae quos veritatis similique tempora dolorem tempore suscipit rerum obcaecati fugiat in, perspiciatis voluptatibus autem. Ipsam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Обработчик на scroll. После события проверять, не оказался ли в зоне видимости ваш объект. Если да - залить цветом.

Comment: Есть любопытное API: [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/fpkr4oga/). Правда только в хроме работает, так что точно не для проды.

Comment: https://github.com/camwiegert/in-view

Answer (score 3):

```js
textHighlighting();

function textHighlighting() {
  const $window = $(window);
    
  onScroll();
  $window.bind('scroll', onScroll);
  
  function onScroll() {
    const $text = $('.text:not(.color)'),
      scroll = $window.scrollTop(),
      windowHeight = $window.height();
      
    if($text.length === 0) $window.unbind('scroll', onScroll);
    
    $text.each(function() {
      const $this = $(this),
        textTop = $this.offset().top,
        textHeight = $this.innerHeight();
      
      // Как только хотя бы один пиксель появляется на экране
      // if(scroll + windowHeight > textTop && scroll < textTop + textHeight) {
      //   $this.addClass('color');
      // }
      
      // Когда текст целиком помещается на экране
      if(scroll + windowHeight >= textTop + textHeight && scroll <= textTop) {
        $this.addClass('color');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
}

.color {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ea tenetur, quibusdam, dolor vel molestiae quos veritatis similique tempora dolorem tempore suscipit rerum obcaecati fugiat in, perspiciatis voluptatibus autem. Ipsam.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ea tenetur, quibusdam, dolor vel molestiae quos veritatis similique tempora dolorem tempore suscipit rerum obcaecati fugiat in, perspiciatis voluptatibus autem. Ipsam.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ea tenetur, quibusdam, dolor vel molestiae quos veritatis similique tempora dolorem tempore suscipit rerum obcaecati fugiat in, perspiciatis voluptatibus autem. Ipsam.</p>
</div>
```