# Как запустить этот скрипт когда его объект виден?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Мне нужно чтобы этот скрипт выполнялся только тогда, когда его объект в зоне видимости.

Скрипт эмулирует окрашивание текста.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

```js
$(window).click(function() {
  if ($('#transparent').html())
    reset();
  else
    move_symbols();
});

const n = 3;  // Число перекидываемых символов за один раз (влияет на скорость)

function move_symbols()  {
// Перекидывает один несколько символов из одного <span> в другой, из #ordinary в #transparent
  var a = $('.transparent').html();
  var b = $('.ordinary').html(); 
  a += b.substring(0, n);
  b = b.substring(n);
  $('.transparent').html(a);
  $('.ordinary').html(b);
  
  // Если не достигнут конец текста, то повторить через короткое время
  if (b) id = setTimeout(move_symbols, 1);
}

function reset() {
  clearTimeout (id);
  var a = $('.transparent').html();
  var b = $('.ordinary').html(); 
  b = a + b;
  $('.transparent').html('');
  $('.ordinary').html(b);
}
```

```css
.block + .block {
margin-top: 200px;
}
.block {
position: relative;
}

.not-marked {z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
}
.selected {background: yellow;}
.transparent {opacity: 0;}
.ordinary {color: #cccccc; background: white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">

<div class="not-marked">
<span class="transparent"></span><span class="ordinary">Notre feuille de route etait claire : valoriser l’incroyable apport de Citroen a l’histoire de l’industrie automobile et celebrer son eternelle originalite en produisant un site a la navigation innovante. Pour ce faire, nous avons imagine une veritable plongee virtuelle dans 49 des modeles les plus iconiques du constructeur. De la 10 HP Type A de 1919 a la C3 3eme generation en passant par des modeles de competition mais egalement des concept cars, chaque vehicule a droit a des vues panoramiques exterieures mais aussi interieures.</span>
</div>

<div>
<span class=selected>Notre feuille de route</span> etait claire : <span class=selected>valoriser</span> l’incroyable apport de Citroen a l’histoire de l’industrie automobile et <span class=selected>celebrer</span> son eternelle originalite en produisant un site a la navigation innovante. Pour ce faire, nous avons imagine une veritable plongee virtuelle dans <span class=selected>49 des modeles les plus iconiques du constructeur.</span> De la 10 HP Type A de 1919 a la C3 3eme generation en passant par des modeles de competition mais egalement des concept cars, chaque vehicule a droit a des vues <span class=selected>panoramiques exterieures mais aussi interieures</span>.
</div>

</div>

<div class="block">

<div class="not-marked">
<span class="transparent"></span><span class="ordinary">Notre feuille de route etait claire : valoriser l’incroyable apport de Citroen a l’histoire de l’industrie automobile et celebrer son eternelle originalite en produisant un site a la navigation innovante. Pour ce faire, nous avons imagine une veritable plongee virtuelle dans 49 des modeles les plus iconiques du constructeur. De la 10 HP Type A de 1919 a la C3 3eme generation en passant par des modeles de competition mais egalement des concept cars, chaque vehicule a droit a des vues panoramiques exterieures mais aussi interieures.</span>
</div>

<div>
<span class=selected>Notre feuille de route</span> etait claire : <span class=selected>valoriser</span> l’incroyable apport de Citroen a l’histoire de l’industrie automobile et <span class=selected>celebrer</span> son eternelle originalite en produisant un site a la navigation innovante. Pour ce faire, nous avons imagine une veritable plongee virtuelle dans <span class=selected>49 des modeles les plus iconiques du constructeur.</span> De la 10 HP Type A de 1919 a la C3 3eme generation en passant par des modeles de competition mais egalement des concept cars, chaque vehicule a droit a des vues <span class=selected>panoramiques exterieures mais aussi interieures</span>.
</div>

</div>
<div class="block">

<div class="not-marked">
<span class="transparent"></span><span class="ordinary">Notre feuille de route etait claire : valoriser l’incroyable apport de Citroen a l’histoire de l’industrie automobile et celebrer son eternelle originalite en produisant un site a la navigation innovante. Pour ce faire, nous avons imagine une veritable plongee virtuelle dans 49 des modeles les plus iconiques du constructeur. De la 10 HP Type A de 1919 a la C3 3eme generation en passant par des modeles de competition mais egalement des concept cars, chaque vehicule a droit a des vues panoramiques exterieures mais aussi interieures.</span>
</div>

<div>
<span class=selected>Notre feuille de route</span> etait claire : <span class=selected>valoriser</span> l’incroyable apport de Citroen a l’histoire de l’industrie automobile et <span class=selected>celebrer</span> son eternelle originalite en produisant un site a la navigation innovante. Pour ce faire, nous avons imagine une veritable plongee virtuelle dans <span class=selected>49 des modeles les plus iconiques du constructeur.</span> De la 10 HP Type A de 1919 a la C3 3eme generation en passant par des modeles de competition mais egalement des concept cars, chaque vehicule a droit a des vues <span class=selected>panoramiques exterieures mais aussi interieures</span>.
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: То есть если мы доскролили до текста то он окрасился. Доскролили до следующего - тоже окрасился.

Comment: Я же тут уже давал пример по видимости: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709329/242887 Может лучше накидаешь окончательный вариант этого блока, чем на каждую новую фишку переписывать одно и то же?